# Improve warning box color when editing a previous version of a post

Tags: feature-request, edits, design, user-experience

When editing a previous version of a post, the following warning box shows.

[image: warning box shows when editing a previous version of a post - dark mode]

As you see, there's a red dotted border around the box, which I think is quite unclear.

Can it be fixed to be similar to the "How to Edit" box?

[image: the "How to Edit" box]

It could be improved in the "light" mode as well as the "dark" mode.

[image: warning box shows when editing a previous version of a post - light mode]